# Information of key word is stored in word document, when user clicks on excel cell with keyword , info of keyword shuold get displayed via word Dox

Tags: excel, vba, search

'i have an excel where diffrent cell has a keyword,
Information about various keywords is stored in a word documnet
I want whenever someone clicks on the cell with keyword, word document should get open and display respective keyword information ( as if the cell value is being cntrl+F in word and brought in front)'

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim strfindword As String
'        strfindword = InputBox("What are you looking for?", "Find", "") ' what word to find?

strfindword = "derivatives"
            If WebPageContains(strfindword) = True Then 'check if the word is in page
                MsgBox "The webpage contains the text" 'string is in page
            Else
                MsgBox "The webpage doesn't contains the text" 'string is not in page
            End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 WebBrowser1.Navigate2 "C:\Users\Chetan\Documents\test.htm.mht"
End Sub
Private Function WebPageContains(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, EHTML
    For i = 1 To WebBrowser1.Document.All.Length
        Set EHTML = _
        WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item(i)
 
 
        If Not (EHTML Is Nothing) Then
            If InStr(1, EHTML.innerHTML, _
            s, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            WebPageContains = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, what have you tried? SO is not a code writing service so you have to do your own research first, attempt it then ask a question here if you have a problem.

Comment: Very New to this platform, Please check again. I am not able to debug this

Comment: In your code, I see that you have one that opens Word and a document but in `Macro2`, there's nothing that pulls keyword from the cells. You need to provide more information: 1) How are the keywords stored in your excel sheet? Can you provide the cell range that stores the keywords (or screenshot of your worksheet)? 2) Are you looking to show the first keyword found in the document or what? Provide a screenshot of your expected output would help.

Comment: i changed my code, i am presenting my word  Document in browser window Now i need to focus on the part where my word is in browser page.

Comment: Your question title and description is no longer accurate in that case then. It is no longer a word document and you are no longer extracting keyword from excel. Either close this and post a new question or edit the entire question (title, question, tag) please. @ChetanPalve